# Is this a pattern, or similar to a pattern, and what's its name

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have 3 classes:

- an interface class that defines a few methods
- 2 classes which implement that interface `Class_A` and `Class_B`

I then have a class which basically chooses which class (A or B) to instantiate based on some condition

```
class Chooser
{
   public static function choose($condition)
   {
      $class = 'Class_' . ucfirst($condition);  
      return new $class();
   }
}
```

I then call the static choose method and it returns an instance of the right class (A or B)

```
Chooser::choose($condition);
```

My questions:

- first of all, is this a valid pattern (or close to a pattern), and what is its name
- if it's close to a pattern, how can I modify so it's a proper pattern
- third, the Chooser class is so simple. I could have that logic in my original code instead of `Chooser::choose($condition);`. If I do this, would it now mess with the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call it a pattern as it's concrete code. Patterns are just descriptions of what can be done how. It looks a bit like an implementation of the Factory pattern and if you call it Factory, most users might get a quicker understanding of what it is for.

However it's probably better described as *parametrized object creation*, as you don't verify that the class it generates implements a specific interface, which is part of a common Factory pattern.

That ensures that the function returns a type with a specific interface.

```
class Chooser
{
  /**
   * @return interface
   */
   public static function choose($condition)
   {
      $class = 'Class_' . ucfirst($condition);
      if (!is_a($class, 'interface'))
          return NULL;
      return new $class();
   }
}
```

This needs some specific PHP versions and can be influenced by bugs in PHP because of [`is_a`](http://php.net/is_a). There are alternative ways to check whether a specific classname implements an interface though. I leave this as an exercise.

You need also decide whether the `chooser()` function returns `NULL` if condition does not lead to an object or if it should throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks hakre. The expanded answer really helped :)

Comment: You're welcome. There are often more than one answers to the question, so please keep in mind the other answers (accept and/or upvote them, too).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your example fits in as Factory Pattern. It's one of the creational pattern.

In your original code, do all the coding based upon your interface. The chooser would be responsible for making the correct choice of class to instantiate. You would achieve high separation of concerns by doing it.
Read more about it here.
http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Comment: There is no check for interface in the code given. Does it disqualify the Factory pattern then?

Comment: The basic goal of Factory is to encapsulate the creation of new objects. That seems to be case here, even if there is no interface around.

Comment: @Anand Thanks for your answer too. It was a tough choosing the correct answer. I went with hakre because of the `is_a` point.

Comment: @Anand: The link you provided has an interface. I think every common Factory Pattern has it, because this makes sense. Otherwise it's just an object method returning an object, which could be better described as [Creator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Creator). Just for the context, Factory is a Creator as well, so this is close, but I think it's worth to make a difference because of the Interface.